# Using a layout xml as a template of repeated content in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a template layout which represents each of my rows in a ListView in my app. 
Here is the photorow.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bodylay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/leftbigsquare"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#1000b0"
    android:src="@drawable/test1"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d0b0b0"
        android:textSize="15sp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/righttupperleft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#b170b0"
            android:src="@drawable/test1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightupperright"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#b110b0"
            android:src="@drawable/test1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/righthorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is repeated row by row. What I want to do is to change "ImageView" child, when I load the image from my server not redesign the row layout each time. Each row will show different "leftbigsquare", "rightupperleft", "rightupperright", "righthorizontal" (look at ImageViews ids) photos.

I researched and saw some examples, but they did that by hardcoding the layout such as :

```
LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
    A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

I want to use my photorow.xml as template and just change its attributes such as source in each row.
Is it possible to use my photorow.xml as the template of a row ?

---

### EDIT

My custom adapter :

```
package com.example.test2;

import java.util.List;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PhotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<PhotoRow> rowList;
    Activity context = null;

    public PhotoAdapter(Activity activity, List<PhotoRow> rows) {

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowList = rows;
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;


        rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photorow, null);



        //Here I get the ImageView of my photorow xml
        ImageView leftBigSquare = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.leftbigsquare);


        // Here I get the proper URL from rowList  by using Picasso framework
        Picasso.with(context).load(rowList.get(position).getUrls().get(0))
                .resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(leftBigSquare);

        //So how can I put the leftBigSquare ImageView to my photorow template with its proper attributes


        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can use same rowview XML and still have different data in every row.

You must use a custom adapter and then inflate your row s from that adapter and based on several conditions change your data.

Paste your custom adapter code and I will show you how to do it.